# What causes TransientObjectException during delete in Hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete an entity from my application and I get some errors.

The entities are shown below:

**ClinicInfo**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ClinicInfo extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3352666863795986217L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="appTimezoneId")
    @NotNull
    private AppTimeZone appTimeZone;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

**AppTimeZone**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class AppTimeZone extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 212088957599604285L;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String zoneID;
    ...
    ...
}
```

`PersistentObject` contains both ID and Version in this case.

Whenever I try to delete a `clinicInfo`, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.myapp.entity.AppTimeZone
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)
```

During `ClinicInfo` deletion, I have set only the ID of AppTimeZone object.

Now, why would hibernate checks if AppTimeZone is dirty?

My goal is only to delete a `ClinicInfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your entity object is in detached state, you can't delete it.

You can only delete persistent object. If you have a detached object, you need to first make it persistent by calling `merge()`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However I decided to rewrite the delete function with `hql query` with accept only `Id`.